# my magento website is freaking out the menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

First than all sorry that I can put code here, the best way is to see the live site.

WHen I go to www.theprinterdepo.com, the menu is acting weird on the onmouseover.

However when I go to a product page it works fine.

I am trying to know whats going on in the html but I cant find the problem.

pasting the entire generated html wont do any good.

This is a magento ecommerce site. so either its a problem with html, js or css?

Once detected I could paste the original code that generates that part of the problem

Comment: I am trying to remember the changs I have done lately, and one I remember its this one: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

Comment: I wonder if maybe its a minification process of .JS files?, the problem is to know which one. maybe this?  http://www.theprinterdepo.com/js/varien/menu.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it! There is class named "over" in line 28 on any of your css(may be in assets new.css) remove that class & everything will be fine. Below is the given class.

```
.over {
    left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I am attaching image regarding this class. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19982181/svs.jpg